# Selecting entites in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to make the entities in graphics view selectable, like generally we select the things dragging around. For dragging issue. I used the rubberband feature as:

```
   ui->graphicsView->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::RubberBandDrag);
```

To the entities selectable, in each slot( slots for drawing line, circle etc) I have the set the flags but the item is not getting selected. 
This the code:

```
void MainWindow::drawCircle(){
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
    item2 = new circle;
    scene->addItem(item2);
    qDebug() << "Circle Created";
   item2->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
```

What can I do the make the entities selectable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to be calling setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable) in each slot.
You should set the appropriate flag when a QGraphicsItem is created, either using a pointer to the object:-

```
QGraphicsItem* pItem = new QGraphicsItem(parent);
pItem->setFlag(QGraphpicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
```

or in an inherited QGraphicsItem's constructor.

If you are using an item that inherits from QGraphicsItem, then you need to correctly define its boundingRect function. If the shape of the item is irregular, then you can also override the shape function.

If done correctly, as the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#DragMode-enum) states for RubberBandDrag:-

> *A rubber band will appear. Dragging the mouse will set the rubber band geometry, and all items covered by the rubber band are selected. This mode is disabled for non-interactive views.*

In addition, you appear to be confused as to how to use the QGraphicsView / QGraphicsScene system. A QGraphicsView can be thought of as a window looking into a world, which is the QGraphicsScene.

Create a scene and set the scene to the view just once and then add items to the scene. Following this, your user interacts with the QGraphicsView and scene, not the MainWindow.

The MainWindow is simply a container of the QGraphicsView. In fact, you don't really need a MainWindow at all, unless the QGraphicsView / scene is part of a larger application with other widgets.

When the user clicks their mouse over a QGraphicsView, items whose flags are set to selectable and moveable can be dragged around the scene. If you desire more behaviour you can override the mouse events (mouseMoveEvent, mousePressEvent, mouseReleaseEvent) of the QGraphicsView or even down to the events in a single item.

I suggest taking a look at the [Qt examples for QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-graphicsview.html).

Comment: Yes, I am using the bounding rectangle, but I didn't get you:( Can you provide me the same with a demo so that I can catch you.